# Can I use a websocket library for local tcp socket connections in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm having difficulty finding a robust socket library for doing local tcp socket connections in node.js.

I'm a big fan of using libraries like SockJS or Socket.io for client/server socket connections but I know those use websockets which are different from regular sockets.

I'm wondering if I could use a Websocket library for local connections with similar performance as just using regular sockets or would that include lots of undesired networking overhead?

Basically I want to achieve these three things with sockets and I don't think the native networking module can do them out of the box.

- Monitor the health of each socket in it's pool (Alive or dead).
- Attach an id to each socket so you know where data is coming from
- Build the data from the chunks sent through the sockets

Comment: You need an actual networking library (see the net base library in node: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Comment: I make reference to that library in my question. It's what I meant by the "native networking module".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets are a TCP-like connection, but which actually runs on top of an established HTTP(s) connection (which itself runs within a TCP-connection). This means:

- There is additional overhead: all data gets put into special frames, also you have the HTTP connection establishment additionally to the normal TCP connection establishment.
- They are not compatible with normal sockets, e.g. you need a WebSockets-aware peer on the other side of the connection.

Apart from that they add no additional reliability or features to the underlying TCP connection. E.g. your requirements are already possible with normal sockets.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the "net" module in node.js impliments what I think is called "raw" sockets. There's a server, client and a Socket object but the object doesn't know where if it's alive or dead etc... So I'd have to decorate the socket to achieve these features. I was hoping maybe somebody with experience using the "net" module could verify this but I'm not happy with the additional overhead that you mentioned so it looks like I'm doing the work myself. Great answer. Thank You.

Comment: @JoshElias: Wth TCP you will notice if your connection is broken only if you try to send or receive, there is no other way to check if the connection is dead. If you need this functionality you have to built something like a heartbeat protocol into your application protocol.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense. Any advice on how often I'd "ping" for a heartbeat?

Comment: @JoshElias: That fully depends on how fast you want to detect connection loss.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich actually the nodejs net library exposes the SO_KEEPALIVE option (via socket.KeepAlive) so there is no real need for implementing a hearth beat yourself. I believe this will cause an error to be thrown when the kernel finds out the socket has been closed since there is always an async read on nodejs waiting for new data to arrive on open sockets but I have not tested this.

Comment: @EliAlgranti: SO_KEEPALIVE is not used to detect closed detection (where the peer made a proper TCP shutdown) but dead connections where the peer does not respond anymore. But, the timeout settings are usually global per system and are often multiple hours, so it will not help much.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yeah ok, I was thinking of scenarios where both peers exchange information: if the exchange is frequent enough then you'd know something happened to your peer as soon as you send (and not get an ACK). For infrequent communications keep alive would keep you informed of a dropped connection (a proper shutdown would also cause any async reads to end). I guess for the case where there is only way communication a hearth-beat would be required if the listening peer cannot wait for keep-alive to expire.